# Loading an FPGA pin at 20MHz in parallel

Tags: power, fpga, transmission-line

I'm designing a traction inverter controlled by the [NI sbRIO-9627](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/375466b.pdf), which includes a Zynq-7020 FPGA. I am considering using a single FPGA pin to drive the external clocks of 14x [ADuM7701](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM7701.pdf) isolated ADCs in parallel at 20MHz. I am concerned about trace capacitance/inductance loading down the FPGA pin.

**DC current**

The NI sbRIO-9627 digital outputs are listed as capable of "driving ±3 mA DC loads," whereas the logic input current of the ADuM7701 is ±0.6uA (14 * 0.6uA = 8.4uA), so this should be fine.

**Transmission line**

According to the 1/10th rule, with ϵr=5 and f=20MHz, you'd need a 0.6708m trace to encounter any transmission line issues. However, maybe if there is a large mismatch between source and load impedances I could encounter problems.

*Load impedance*: From my understanding, the load impedance would be the parasitic pin capacitance, which is 10pF for the ADuM7701.

*Source impedance*: The NI sbRIO-9627 digital outputs "are routed with a 55 Ω characteristic trace impedance" which I would have to match, but I can't find information about its parasitic capacitance.

I could do an LTspice simulation of the source, transmission line, and load impedances to see if there will be any issues, however I don't know the characterstics of my PCB yet to estimate the transmission line.

**Going forward**

At 20MHz, should I be concerned about overloading the FPGA pin? Would the source/load impedances typically be small enough to ignore transmission line effects altogether?

Comment: That's what clock fanout buffers are for. But don't use a GPIO pin. You will destroy the accuracy of the sigma delta ADC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't drive an ADC clock with an I/O as a general rule. You really want to be using a separate clock source if you're looking for accuracy.

Comment: Well, you would be okay if it was a successive approximation ADC. But you definitely do not want to do that a sigma-delta ADC, which the ADuM7701 is,  whose accuracy completely hinges on the accuracy of its clock.

Comment: Is the concern the slew rate of the I/O or the accuracy of a digital logic-implemented clock? The NI sbRIO-9627 supports the direct connection of a pin to the global clock distribution buffers in the FPGA. Would you recommend using this along with a clock fanout buffer, or is an external clock source preferable?

Comment: Ideally, I would use an external clock source. The concern is the FPGA not being able to generate an accurate enough clock on an I/O for an ADC. As far as global clock buffers, that usually refers to a clock you INPUT to the FPGA, not output from it. Meaning, any of the global clock pins of the FPGA can be used as the clock inputs and the signal will be available to anywhere in the FPGA. There are other clock cable pins on the FPGA that will only supply the clock to certain parts of the FPGA.